# Openface image embedding on Orange3 Embed Failure

Tags: python, image, embed, orange

[My attempt at using logistic regression with squeezenet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7rZY.png)

I put in ~250 images into orange3 image viewer and I'm attempting to embed the images into a pre-trained facial recognition network (openface) but I don't think orange3 is built to handle such a huge calculation. Is there anyway I can add more memory into Orange3 or transfer the whole process into python? Please let me know if I need to add more information on how I can fix this.

tldr I tried embedding 250 images into orange3 and training the model with the openface network, gave an embed failure.